# Salesforce oAuth JWT Integration

Tags: connected-apps, oauth, jwt

We have provided salesforce self signed certificate to external system for oAuth JWT integration with salesforce. when they hit salesforce they get the below error

What does this error mean and how to fix this error?

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "jti already in use"
}
```

Comment: It needs to be a [unique value](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124624/how-does-jti-prevent-a-jwt-from-being-replayed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JTI is not mandatory in the JWT bearer token but if you send it it should be unique

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

It should a unique number converted to string and passed in through JWT.